# Create a string from a vector of integers in C

Tags: c, string, int

I'm trying to create a string from a vector, something like this:
 `int vector[3] = {1, 2, 3}`.

Then, the string I would get should be:
`[1, 2, 3]` stored in some `char[]` variable.

I tried to do it dynamically like follows:

```
void print_vector(int *vector, int lon){
    char *str = (char*)calloc(3*lon, sizeof(char));
    str[0] = "[";
    str[1] = (char) vector[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < lon; i += 3){
        str[i] = (char)vector[i];
        if(i != lon - 1){
            str[i + 1] = (char)",";
            str[i + 2] = " ";
        }else{
            str[i + 1] = "]";
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Where *lon* is the length of the vector, but I'm getting this warning from the compiler:

*warning: the assignment to "char" from "char *" creates an integer from a pointer without a conversion [-Wint-conversion]*

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `(char)","` should be `','`.

Comment: ^ same applies to all `"["`, `"]"` and `" "` too

Comment: `(char) vector[0];` is not the right way to convert an integer to a string. Consider using [sprintf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm).

Comment: Instead of trying to manipulate the string using `str[i+...]`, consider using [strcat](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm) to build the string. This will also take care of the nul-terminator at the end that you have missed.

Comment: How big are the numbers in the vector?  You show single-digit numbers; are all your numbers single-digit numbers, or can you have tens, hundreds, thousands, millions, billions?  What about negative numbers?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya — using `strcat()` is probably not a good idea if the vectors can be long (because you get quadratic performance unless you carefully keep track of the end of the string you're adding to — and if you keep track of the end, using `strcpy()` is adequate).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right! `sprintf` with `%n` should help track the length without additional overhead. Or just calls to `strlen` while tracking the pointer.

Comment: Or use the return value from `snprintf()` (or `sprintf()`) which tells you how many characters were added to the string, excluding the trailing null.

Comment: The code in the question leaks memory because there is no `free()` before the return, and there is no return value from the function.  It's also not a compelling solution if you print the string in the function.  You only need to build the string if you're going to use it in some function you call (other than something as simple as the `printf()` shown), or if you return it.  To some extent, you can plead "simplified to fit on SO", but think about the design and always think about memory leaks.

Comment: Note that the loop `for (int i = 1; i < lon; i += 3){` would only include the `2` in the result for the data given.  You should probably use `for (int i = 0; i < lon; i++)` and index into the string using a different variable that is incremented separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code -

1. You are using `"` instead of `'`. `"` is used to create a string literal which is of type `char*`. Hence the error you are getting.
2. `(char) vector[0];` is not the right way to convert an integer to strings. You should use something like [`sprintf`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm).
3. You haven't allocated enough memory with the call to `calloc` (the brackets, commas, space, nul-terminator).
4. You are only filling in certain characters in the buffer. The rest are initialized to `0`. This will cause the string to terminate earlier than expected.

To start, you can fix your code as -

```
void print_vector(int *vector, int lon){

    char *str = calloc(5*lon+3, sizeof(char)); 
    // 5 for each character (3 characters per integer + space + comma. 
    // Two brackets and nul-terminator

    strcpy(str, "[");

    if (lon) {
        sprintf(str+1, "%d", vector[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i < lon; i++){
            sprintf(str + strlen(str), ", %d", vector[i]);
        }
    }

    strcat(str, "]");

    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

You can find the working demo [here on ideone](https://ideone.com/jfiJK0).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign strings to `char` array elements. You need to use single quotes to create `char` constants.

So

```
str[0] = "[";
```

should be

```
str[0] = '[';
```

and similarly for all the other assignments.

Another problem is that `(char)vector[i]` will not return the character representation of the number in `vector[i]`. It simply uses the integer as the character code. So if `vector[i]` is 1, this produces `'\1'`, not `'1'`. The way to get the character representation of a number is with `'0' + vector[i]`.

Finally, you need to add a null terminator to the end of the string so you can print it with `%s` formatting. And you should free it before returning to prevent a memory leak.

Other problems: You're only putting every 3rd element of `vector` into the string. You need to use separate indexes for `vector` and `str`. And array indexes start at `0`, not `1`.

```
void print_vector(int *vector, int lon){
    char *str = (char*)calloc(3*lon, sizeof(char));
    str[0] = "[";
    str[1] = (char) vector[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < lon; i++){
        str[i*3] = '0' + vector[i];
        if(i != lon - 1){
            str[i*3 + 1] = ',';
            str[i*3 + 2] = ' ';
        }else{
            str[i*3 + 1] = ']';
            str[i*3 + 2] = '\0';
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every element in your vector is one digit, and every element is spaced identicially...

... and remembering you need to allicate a null byte at the end to terminate your string...

... perhaps something like this (uncompiled/untested):

```
void print_vector(int *vector, int lon){
    char *str = (char*)calloc((3*lon)+1, sizeof(char));
    char *s = str;
    *s++ = "[";
    int i=1;
    while (i < lon) {
      *s++ = vector[i] + 0x30;  // ASCII "0"= 0x30, "1"= 0x31, ...
      *s++ = ',';
      *s++ = ' ';
      i++;
    }   
    s -= 2;
    *s++ = ']';
    *s++ = 0;
    printf("%s\n", str);
```

Comment: `*s++ = "[";` doesn't compile. `int i=1;` --> `int i=0;` `vector[i] + 0x30` --> `vector[i] + '0'`